# Catching Errors from Promise construction

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

Is there a better way of doing the following using Bluebird promises

```
Promise.resolve()
    .then(function() {return new MyObject(data)})
    .then.....etc
    .catch(function (e){ //handle it})
```

I have MyObject - and data passed in from an external system, which could be invalid, thus could break the promise chain. Wrapping the object creation in a function in a then seems really messy tho. Is there something like

```
Promise.something(new MyObject(data))
       .then()....
       .catch....
```

Also - Node 0.10 so no Lambda to make it look tidier :-(

Comment: If you're getting `data` from a prior promise you'll need to use `then` one way or another. What exactly are you looking for? A way to reduce `function (data) { return new MyObject(data) }`?

Comment: Are you possibly looking for [`Promise.resolve(new MyObject(data))`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.resolve.html) to generate a promise from `MyObject`?

Comment: @zzzzBov it sounds like OP wants the promise to catch any exceptions `new MyObject` may throw (@Silver, is that right?)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than `Promise.something(new MyObject(data))`, which runs `new MyObject` **before** creating the Promise, use the long-form promise constructor:

```
new Promise(function (resolve) {
  resolve(new MyObject(data));
}.then(foo).catch(bar);
```

Exceptions thrown **synchronously** within a promise constructor or `then` callback will be caught, processed (including type matching), and sent on to `catch` handlers ([Bluebird docs](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/catch.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is, `Promise.try`, also you should be using arrows for short function expressions in Node:

```
Promise.try(() => new MyObject(data));
```

Like in browsers, you can use [a transpiler](https://babeljs.io/repl) for old versions of Node.

Also, I would not perform IO in a constructor  but that's another story. The other answer by ssube explains why a constructor is needed because exceptions occur before the method is actually called.